# javax.persistence.query.timeout for extended periods

Tags: java, jpa, timeout, database-connection, jpql

For JPA connections, I can set a timeout so that between queries the connection will stay open?

```
<properties>
   <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="3000"/>
</properties>
```

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/setting#Query_Hints_

While I'm aware that the preference is for reconnection, for now I would prefer to simply keep the connection alive.  This is the correct way to keep the connection alive?

Comment: I think this property just throws QueryTimeoutException if timeout is reached. If you want to re-use connections you might have to use some kind of connection pool in combination with JPA, such as DBCP. Or you can use connections obtained from application server via JNDI and let application server to handle connection management.

Comment: That is JPA provider specific since your provider is also your DB provider. Consult their docs if they even mention such a thing